# Win Vista Sysprep error 50 in recovery command prompt

Tags: windows-vista, restore, system-restore, system-recovery

I am dealing with a desktop with hardware failed due to a mainboard issue. Replacement mainboards also have the same, known problem; so, I installed a new model mainboard and CPU. Of course, Vista won't boot into safe mode, and auto-repair is helpless.

I want to generalize the windows installation with SYSPREP; because, the system has an obscure legacy application for which we (for unknown reasons) no longer have install media. The only way I can get to a command line (that I know of) is through the system repair command line. I am able to access C:\ and execute its copy of SYSPREP. However, I encounter the following error:

> 2015-06-03 21:03:18, Error    [0x0f0082] SYSPRP LaunchDll:Failure occurred while executing 'X:\Windows\System32\wevtapi.dll,EvtIntSysprepCleanup', returned error code 50[gle=0x00000032]
>
> 2015-06-03 21:03:18, Error    [0x0f0070] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:An error occurred while running registry sysprep DLLs, halting sysprep execution. dwRet = 50[gle=0x00000032]
>
> 2015-06-03 21:03:18, Error    [0x0f00a8] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while processing sysprep cleanup providers; hr = 0x80070032[gle=0x00000032]

I assume this happens because X:\ has the active operating system during recovery, and SYSPREP is trying to prepare the X: drive.

Is there any way to target the C: drive if recovery mode? I very much prefer to save us days of application installation and configuration, and the loss of the legacy application.

Thanks in advance for your help!